# Bootstrap table how to change value using input box in data-formatter

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table to display my data. I used a data formatter on a column like:

```
function inputFormatter(value, row){
    return '<input class="form-control data-input" value="' + value + '">';
}
```

My bootstrap column:

```
<th data-field="channel_sku" data-align="center" data-formatter="inputFormatter">Channel SKU</th>
```

Now the data appears as value in an input box for that column like:

[image: Data Formatted as per function.]

Now the problem is when I change the text in the input box the value of that cell doesn't change. i.e When I send data to my backend using ajax, I get the old data. Also the value attribute in input box doesn't change to the new value.

So How Can I change the value of that cell on text input?

Comment: You need to add a `blur` event to input textbox and update the value of respective `th`.. If you could create a snippet or fiddle, we could possibly help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a workaround too. I catched the event on clicking the table stored the row index and field in a global varible.

Every time a cell is clicked upon, the value of these global vars will change to the new value of that cell.

```
$('#sku-map-table').bootstrapTable({
    onClickCell: function (field, value, row, $element) {
        $rowIndex = $element.closest('tr').attr('data-index');
        $field = field;
    }
});
```

Then I catched the input boxes using `data-input` class and updated that value of cell with the new value.

```
$(document).on('change', '.data-input', function(event) {
    $new_val = $(this).val();
    $('#sku-map-table').bootstrapTable('updateCell', {index: $rowIndex, field: $field, value: $new_val});
});
```

Summary is to change the value of input box , one has to click on the respective cell and that's what I used.

Comment: if you have a unique column, you can also use [Update Cell By Unique Id](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#methods/update-cell-by-unique-id.html), but don't forget to set the attribute 'data-unique-id' on your table

Answer (score 0):

I've started working with this library on Monday and I'm full of questions as well, sad for us that apparently there isn't enough info or questions in SO as for today.

The problem here is that the value of an input it's different to the one the `bootstrapTable('getData')` method fetches, this method fetches the values of the properties that conform the objects that conform the list you passed to the table `data` parameter when constructing the table first. When you change the value of an input, the data object the table has remains unchanged, that's why you keep getting old data, you need to update the values on the data object every time your input triggers an `onChange` event, this can be achieved with the `bootstrapTable('updateCell', params)` method which receives the following parameters as described on the manual.

> index: the row index. 
>   field: the field name.
>   value: the new field value. 
>   To disable table re-initialization you can set {reinit: false}

I came up with this workaround today as I wanted to implement inputs on my columns as well, here are my column attributes:

```
{field: 'varillasEnLecho', title: 'Varilla en lecho', formatter: function(value, row, index) {
    return '<input class="form-control data-input" value="' + value + '" row-index="' + index + '" field="varillasEnLecho"  onchange="updateCell($(this))">';
  }
}
```

and here's the function the input triggers on change:

```
function updateCell(caller) {
  var table = caller.parents('table');
  var newData = {
    index: caller.attr('row-index'), field: caller.attr('field'), value: caller.val(), reinit: false
  };

  table.bootstrapTable('updateCell', newData);

  var data = JSON.stringify(table.bootstrapTable('getData'));
  console.log(data);
}
```

It works correctly, here's a screenshot:

[image: table]

**Foreword**: Bootstrap Table has a sweet extension called [x-editable](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable) that manages editable cells and automatically updates the data model the table is based on, you can see how it is implemented in this [example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/editable.html), and here's how it looks:[image: x-editable]

What do you want to use it's up to you, cheers.